# Compare two distributions with discrete variables

Tags: distributions

I am trying to understand which kind of test I could use in order to test if two distributions differ significantly from each other.
My data has the following structure: I have for two countries the numbers of cars sold per 100,000 citizens for 5 different car manufacturers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What exactly do you want to test? I see three variables here: cars sold (adjusted for population), nation, and car manufacturer.

Comment: How do you obtain these numbers?  The normal way is through samples in which you count the sales, but there are other ways.  How you analyze the results depends on the data.  Why? Consider the differences between one study that asked one car dealership for its records and another study that conducted a survey of a million citizens asking about what models of cars they own.

Comment: @Dave Thank you! I'd like to test if there's a difference between the two nations. So whether the sales per 100,000 citizens and per car manufacturer are similar enough to say that there is not a significant difference or there is.

Comment: @whuber The numbers were obtained by counting the sales for each of the car manufacturers for both countries

Comment: One would naturally present these data with a $2\times 5$ contingency table of counted data: one row for each country and one column for each car model showing its total sales in each country.  Your question sounds like a standard one of asking whether the rows reflect a common underlying probability distribution or not.  Is that your question?  If so, look into applying a chi-squared test.  If not, how do your circumstances differ?

Comment: @whuber, I think yes, I'd like to find out if the distribution of nation1 and the distribution of nation2 could be drawn from the same underlying distribution. Thank you for your help, I will look into chi-squared tests.